# Remove one occurrence of a duplicate string from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do you remove only one occurrence of a given string from an array if there are duplicates? Assume that the array is ordered alphanumerically.

For example, if I have the following array `['a1', 'b2', 'b2', 'c1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2']`, and I call call `removeString('b2')`, how would I get `removeString` to output `['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2']`?

Comment: Is your expected array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`?

Comment: The original dataset along with the expected result can vary, I just want to know how to remove only one occurrence of a given string if there are duplicates.

Comment: Is it always ordered?

Comment: Yes it is always ordered

Comment: Can you add the array that you expect as your output to the question?

Comment: if the original is ['a1', 'b2', 'b2', 'c1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2'], then the expected output is ['a1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c1', 'd2', 'e2'] for this example

Comment: Wait, are you looking to remove duplicates or is this a different question?

Comment: if it is `["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d"]` what should the output look like?

Comment: one occurrence of a duplicate, in this case, the duplicate is b2. Sorry if question was worded ambiguously.

Comment: if the original is ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d"] and i'm looking to remove a 'b', then the expected output is ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `findIndex` to find the first index of a repeat (compared to the previous item in the array). If one is found, we *mutate* the original array using the `splice()` method.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const found = array.findIndex((el, i) => {
  return i > 0 && el === array[i - 1];
})

if (found) {
  array.splice(found, 1);
}

console.log(array);
```